# then() method only opening up the same link

Tags: casperjs

I have an array of links and the follow code is supposed to open up each link in the array of links.

```js
var x; var i = 0;

casper.start(URL, function() {
    x = links.split(" "); // now x is an array of links
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.each(x, function() { 
        this.thenOpen((partialURL + x[i]), function() {
            this.echo(this.getTitle()); // display the title of page
            i++; // change the link being opened
        });
    });
});

casper.run();
```

The problem is that it opens up the first link and just keeps opening that link over and over again. It's like `i` isn't changing.

One of the CasperJS examples had the same problem where for Twitter followers, it would open up the link for each Twitter follower, but it would display one name (the last one in the list) the entire time.

Here is the example:

```js
var users = ['subelsky','bmorejs'];
var casper = require('casper').create();

var idx,data,user;
var length = users.length;

casper.start();

for (idx=0; idx < length; idx++) {
    user = users[idx];

    casper.thenOpen('http://mobile.twitter.com/' + user,function() {
        data = this.evaluate(function(location) {
            return document.querySelector('div.profile td.stat.stat-last div.statnum').innerText;
        });
        this.echo(user + ": " + data);
    });
}

casper.run();
```

The output would be `bmorejs: 2861 followers` and `bmorejs: 503 followers`

Can this be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it runs through all of the links before it gets into the function for `thenOpen`, and instead just opens the links. It's an easy fix.

Simply move your `i++;` statement above the `thenOpen` method, and that way it will be sure to change before it opens a new link. Also, change the initial value of `i` to be `-1` so that when it runs `i++;`, it won't skip to `1` right away.

Your code would change to the following:

```js
var x; var i = -1;          

casper.start(URL, function() {
    x = links.split(" "); // now x is an array of links
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.each(x, function() { 
        i++; // change the link being opened (has to be here specifically)
        this.thenOpen((partialURL + x[i]), function() {
            this.echo(this.getTitle()); // title should now be different
        });
    });
});

casper.run();
```